# Less than comparison not working after $filter is applied to 3 digit negative numbers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Once $filter is used on 3 or more digit negative number, then less than comparison operator is not working properly.

```js
var num = -1500;
num = $filter('number')(num, 0);
if (num <= 15) {
      console.log("working");
}
```

This is found for all negative numbers below -999.5

But it's interesting to see that this works when condition is

```
 if (num <= $filter('number')(15, 0))
```

Any idea why this is happening ?

Answer (score 1):

Return value of number filter is :

```
Number rounded to decimal Places and places a “,” after each third digit.
```

Ref: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number

So this `,` creates issue in your `if` condition

Here is the solution for it,

```
var num = -1500;
num = $filter('number')(num, 0);
if (num.replace(",", "") <= 15) {
    console.log("working");
}
```

But I don't think this is the proper way to do it.